# ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 'Toyota'

Tags: python

[DataFrame screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXD5M.png)

DataFrame Graph:

[image: DataFrame Graph]

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

sns.barplot(x=ncs_2007_2017.index, y='Units Sold', data=ncs_2007_2017)

for i in range(len(ncs_2007_2017.index)):
    plt.text(i, ncs_2007_2017['Make'].iloc[i], str(ncs_2007_2017['Make'].iloc[i]), ha='center', va='center')

plt.show()
```

```
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: 'Toyota'
```

I am a newbie in data analysis can anyone here helps me how to fix this error?

Comment: You need to make a [mre] including your data as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code). As well, you need to include complete code and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: What are you trying to do friend? Are you trying to add how do i say this a car label?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814857/conversionerror-failed-to-convert-values-to-axis-units)

Answer (score 0):

second argument in `plt.text(i, ncs_2007_2017['Make'].iloc[i],str(ncs_2007_2017['Make'].iloc[i]), ha='center', va='center')` is y position in image (barplot). `ncs_2007_2017['Make'].iloc[i]` gives string data from column `make` like **Toyota**. Convert it to some integer like `int(ncs_2007_2017['Units Sold'].iloc[i])+1000` for second argument.

```
 plt.text(i,int(ncs_2007_2017['Units Sold'].iloc[i])+1000, str(ncs_2007_2017['Make'].iloc[i]), ha='center', va='center')
```

It will write your text on top of each bar